# rails forms:how do i blur a field when a particular option is selected in another field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

This is gonna be my first attempt at javascript. When someone selects a particular option in a select list, I want another field in the form to go dull because it's no longer applicable. I guess I have to write an onchange event handler and have it execute a javascript script that detects the selected option and renders a  form with the relevant field dull if the option's selected or renders a different form if a different option was selected ... anyone can give me a start please ~ thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$(document).on('blur', "selector", function (e) { 
  // do what you want to do, change background, color, etc...
});
```

Instead of `selector` type in the class, id, or other selector for the element you need to change.

You can add this snippet to any javascript file included in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. You can create a new one and add it there if none existing suits you...

If `application.js` ends with `//= require_tree .` it means that it will require all files in that directory and you do not need to manually require them.

Btw, concerning the terminology, element has focus when it is clicked on. When element looses focus (for example some other element is clicked, or tab is pressed), it gets blured. That is when on('blur') gets called.

This is how you can write on('change') for a select:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
  // do something
});
```

Instead of 'select' you need to type in the correct selector, otherwise it will get triggered each time any select changes.

> I need the action to be triggered only when i specific value in the
>   select list is selected

No problem, try this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 'specific_value'){
    // do something
  }
});
```

---

UPDATE

> I wanna make the call to jquery from my view and replace the element
>   in the view with the output of the jquery filename.js.erb file

jQuery, and all other javascript is being executed within the client (the web browser), and your file `filename.js.erb` is located on the server, and it needs to be processed by rails.

This is how it can be done:

1. ajax request is sent to the server
2. it gets picked up by rails, and it is routed to a controller
3. it is processed by a controller action
4. a javascript view is rendered and posted as a response

There are two ways to achieve this. First I will explain the steps that are common for both approaches.

You will need to add a new route to your `routes.rb` that you will use as an endpoint for your ajax call. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) you can read more about adding routes to rails, but for the purpose of this answer, I will use this simple route (with a dumb name, you should change that for sure):

```
resource :my_ajax, only: :create
```

And this is what the route looks like:

```
rake routes|grep my_ajax
# my_ajax POST    /my_ajax(.:format)   my_ajaxes#create
```

It expects that you have `MyAjaxesController`, and within it `create` action. You should also make your controller able to respond to javascript requests by adding this to the controller:

```
class MyAjaxesController < AdminController
  # ...
  respond_to :js
  # ...

  def create
    # ...
  end
end
```

You also need to have a view for that action: `create.js.erb`. You can add javascript to that view, but there you can also make use of everything rails controller makes available for you. So, you can use any instance variables or you can render partials.

This is how a partial can be rendered:

```
$('#element').html('<%= j(render partial: "_my_partial", locals: { my_var: @my_var }) %>');
```

When the response to ajax request is received by the browser, it just replaces the contents of `#element` with whatever html got rendered by that partial.

Ok, coming now to the differences to the approaches.

You could send an ajax request (by jQuery) aiming to the endpoint that you created (mind the method, the route I created expects POST). In that case you need to manually manage any response you receive.

However, there is a rails way of doing it. You could create a form with all of its fields hidden (you don't need it in the view, you just need it as a means to send a request). You need to specify the action for the form, the method, and also set `remote: true`, to make sure that it is submitted asynchronously.

Here's an example:

```
<%= form_tag(my_ajax_path, remote: true, method: :post) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :some_field %>
<% end %>
```

All you need to do is submit this form whenever you want (for example by looking it up with an id and calling submit: `$('#my_form').submit();` and it will do the rest. You can also dynamically change any hidden inputs of the form prior to submitting.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 'specific_value'){
    $('#my_form').submit();
  }
});
```

As for the testing the controller action by rspec, in order for it to work, do not forget that what controller expects and renders is javascript requests, so you need to specify the format:

```
it 'my test' do
  # expectations
  response = post :my_ajax, format: :js
  # assertions
end
```

Comment: thanks ... i need the action to be triggered only when i specific value in the select list is selected

Comment: thanks, instead of loading a whole new form page i just wanna render a partial containing the explanation field into the form by using the field's label,  "explaination" so i tried this but it didn't work

Comment: <script>
$(#explanation).on('change', 'reason', function (e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 'I can't explain'){
  render 'read_only_explanation_field'
  }
});
</script>

Comment: in my view  <div class="field" id="explanation">

Comment: you can not render a rails partial by javascript. With jquery you cold call $('#element').html('...') and replace its content, but you can not call "render". In order to do so, you would need to send a remote request to rails, and do it in a javascript view. Would you like me to update the answer with an example?

Comment: I wanna make the call to jquery from my view and replace the element in the view with the output of the jquery filename.js.erb file

Comment: "With jquery you cold call $('#element').html('...') and replace its content " ... that's what i wanna do

Comment: I have updated the answer, please take a look. Yes, you can do it via jqery, but you can not call rails render method within jquery, it needs to be processed by erb.

Comment: The purpose of jquery is to render the form or partial thereof whose purpose in turn is to submit itself to a create action The create action doesn't come into play until the form's been submitted So why am I writing a create action to effect the rendering of the form

Comment: it's a different create action of a different controller. The purpose of one create action (and it is "create" because we want to POST) is to render something by rails, and the purpose of the other is that you add to the database whatever you need. You need to manipulate the form, and as I answered you can do that client side (javascript) but if you want to involve the server side (rails) you need to send the request to the server.

Comment: so, in simple terms, if you render the page with the form in it, and if you send an asynchronous request to the server, it may manipulate the form without reloading the page. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `change` event of jquery.
For example your option select like this:

```
<%= f.select :state, [['NSW'], ['VIC'], ['SA'], ['WA'], ['QLD']] %>
```

Then, you have to create jquery event to do your next action. For example:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   // hidding form
   $("#form_1").hide();
   $("#form_2").hide();
   // showing form after user changes the select option
    $("#user_state").change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).val();
      if(selected == "VIC") {
        $("#form_1").show();
      } else {
        $("#form_2").show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I hope this help you to attempt the first experience for trying jquery. Good luck!